# How to click on QMessageBox with pytest-qt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pytest, pytest-qt

I am creating some unit tests for a `PyQt` application with `pytest-qt`.
And I would like to create open the graphical window, do some tests then close the window, rather than open a new window for every test, ie. use a module fixture for the window itself.
I succeeded to do this part, by calling in a local function a `QtBot` rather than using the default fixture, and removing the mocker ones. So I am pretty close to my objective.

However, but I am not able to close the window (and test the `QMessageBox` for closing event).

I red examples like 
[how to handle modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336575/how-to-handle-modal-dialog-in-pytest-qt-without-mocking-the-dialog) and its [git](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/256) discussion, or the [qmessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382773/functional-test-for-qmessagebox-why-does-not-work) question; which seem to be close to my question.
It is suggested to use a timer to wait for the `QMessageBox` to appear then click on a button choice, but visibly I am not able to apply them correctly.
In my attempt, `pytest` get the closing demand, but not the click on the `dialog` box. So, I have to click myself to finish the test.

Here is a small example, with file `GUI.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(self)

    def initUI(self, MainWindow):
        # centralwidget
        MainWindow.resize(346, 193)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        # The Action to quit
        self.toolb_action_Exit = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        self.toolb_action_Exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.toolb_action_Exit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        # The Button
        self.btn_prt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_prt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 89, 25))
        self.btn_prt.clicked.connect(lambda: self.doPrint() )
        self.btn_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 20, 89, 25))
        self.btn_quit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close() )

        # The textEdit
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 321, 81))

        # Show the frame
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()

    def doPrint(self):
        print('TEST doPrint')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Ask a question before to quit.
        self.replyClosing = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
            QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if self.replyClosing == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


def main_GUI():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = Example()
    return app, imageViewer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app, imageViewer =main_GUI()
    rc= app.exec_()
    print('App end is exit code {}'.format(rc))
    sys.exit(rc)
```

and the `pytest` file named `test_GUI.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
import pytest

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtTest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject

from pytestqt.plugin import QtBot

GUI = __import__('GUI')


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="module")
def qtbot_session(qapp, request):
    print("  SETUP qtbot")
    result = QtBot(qapp)
    with capture_exceptions() as exceptions:
        yield result
    print("  TEARDOWN qtbot")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def Viewer(request):
    print("  SETUP GUI")
    app, imageViewer = GUI.main_GUI()
    qtbotbis = QtBot(app)
    # qtbotbis.addWidget(imageViewer)
    # qtbotbis.wait_for_window_shown(imageViewer)
    QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 *1000)
    yield app, imageViewer, qtbotbis

    # EXIT
    # mocker.patch.object(QMessageBox, 'question', return_value=QMessageBox.Yes)
    # imageViewer.toolb_action_Exit.trigger()
    def handle_dialog():
        # while not imageViewer.replyClosing.isVisible():
        #   app.processEvents()
        box = QMessageBox()
        box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes)
        button = box.button(QMessageBox.Yes)
        qtbotbis.mouseClick(button, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, handle_dialog)
    qtbotbis.mouseClick(imageViewer.btn_quit, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, delay=1)
    assert imageViewer.close()
    print("  TEARDOWN GUI")


class Test_GUI() :
    def test_interface(self, Viewer):
        print("  beginning ")
        app, imageViewer, qtbot = Viewer
        qtbot.mouseClick( imageViewer.btn_prt, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton )
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 *1000)
        assert True
        print(" Test passed")
```

Any idea of what I am missing ? Any other idea or suggestion would also be appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your attempt you are creating a new `QMessageBox` that is different from the one created with the static method `QMessageBox::question()` so even if you click it will not work.

The idea is to obtain the `QMessageBox` shown, and in this case we will take advantage of that since it is the active window so we can obtain it using `QApplication::activeWindow()`. Another way to get the QMessageBox is to use the relationship between imageViewer and the QMessageBox through `findChild()`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def Viewer(request):
    print("  SETUP GUI")

    app, imageViewer = GUI.main_GUI()
    qtbotbis = QtBot(app)
    QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 * 1000)

    yield app, imageViewer, qtbotbis

    def handle_dialog():
        messagebox = QtWidgets.QApplication.activeWindow()
        # or
        # messagebox = imageViewer.findChild(QtWidgets.QMessageBox)
        yes_button = messagebox.button(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes)
        qtbotbis.mouseClick(yes_button, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, delay=1)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, handle_dialog)
    qtbotbis.mouseClick(imageViewer.btn_quit, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, delay=1)
    assert imageViewer.isHidden()
```